# Scrappy Sgmllinkextractor Rule did not crawl all defined links

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I would like to crawl all the links in following formats:

```
http://example.com/index.php/comments/XXXXX
http://example.com/XXX1/index.php/comments/XXXXX
http://example.com/XXX2/index.php/comments/XXXX
http://example.com/XXX3/index.php/comments/XXXX
```

And I defined the following rule:

```
start_urls = ['http://example.com/']

rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'\w+/index.php/comments/\w+']), callback='parse_blogpost', follow=True)]
```

But it seemed that the crawler had only visited links like this (http://example.com/index.php/comments/XXXXX) but not link like this (http://example.com/XXX1/index.php/comments/XXXXX).

Any help would be greatly appretiated!

Comment: Try just `index.php/comments` instead of `\w+/index.php/comments/\w+`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried but it didn't work. After a careful investigation, I reckon the reason was there are no links (http://example.com/XXX1/index.php/comments/XXXXX) on web pages of http://example.com/, so the crawler could't follow down to links like http://example.com/XXX1/index.php/comments/XXXXX.